# maven warning "Ignoring unrecognized line ?? release.properties"

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I recently created a github workflow which makes a maven release. I am done fixing the errors, now I am working on fixing the warnings.  One of the warnings reads as follows:

```
Warning:  Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? release.properties
```

Note that this message is in a line all by itself, and it is not prefixed by [WARNING] or anything else. (Still, github finds the "Warning:" prefix and colors it yellow.)

Needless to say, absolutely none of the following can be found anywhere within my project:

- a file called `release.properties`.
- the text `release.properties` in any file.
- the text `??` in any file.

The same warning also appears elsewhere in my log, like this:

```
Warning:  Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? claims/pom.xml.releaseBackup
Warning:  Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? claims/target/
```

("claims" is the name of a directory in my project.)

Interestingly enough, this is also happening to others, because [the relevant google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=maven+Warning+%22Ignoring+unrecognized+line%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com) retrieves many results from people discussing all kinds of things unrelated to this question, and they are posting their logs, and their logs all by coincidence contain the warning that I am asking about. But they are not discussing this warning, they are discussing other things.

If it matters, the workflow is here: https://github.com/mikenakis/Bathyscaphe/runs/6576104769

So, why is this warning being issued, and how might I fix it?

Comment: There *is* a release.properties file, created by mvn release:prepare, and the `?? release.properties` comes from `git status -s`. But I don't know what is parsing the git output and producing the warning.

Comment: The maven-release-plugin check if something needs to be checked in and maybe would fail ...The `pom.xml.releaseBackup` is created during the release process... This can be fixed by adding `pom.xml.releaseBackup` to your `.gitignore` file... the `claims/target` means you have not added `target` to your `.gitignore` or only via `/target`...

Answer (score 0):

The advice I have found (I do not remember where anymore) to solve this problem is:

##### Make sure that maven, git, any maven-plugins you might be using, and everything else in the build toolchain is of the latest version.

There are probably various combinations of versions that work, but it is practically impossible to know which, so using the latest versions is probably the easiest and safest bet.